# NLTagger always returns "otherWord"

Tags: swift

The `NLTagger.enumerateTags` method returns "otherWord" for every word. This problem appear in my simulator. Most of my code is copied directly from [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/naturallanguage/identifying_parts_of_speech).

Here's an example app:

```swift
//  ContentView.swift

import SwiftUI
import NaturalLanguage

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(example())
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

func example() -> String{
    let text = "The ripe taste of cheese improves with age."
    var res = ""
    let tagger = NLTagger(tagSchemes: [.lexicalClass])
    tagger.string = text
    let options: NLTagger.Options = [.omitPunctuation, .omitWhitespace]
    tagger.enumerateTags(in: text.startIndex..<text.endIndex, unit: .word, scheme: .lexicalClass, options: options) { tag, tokenRange in
        if let tag = tag {
            res += "\(text[tokenRange]): \(tag.rawValue)\n"
        }
        return true
    }
    return res
}
```

I'm on Mac OS 13.3.1 (a) and Xcode Version 14.3.1

Comment: When I copy the code from your `example` method into a Swift Playground with Xcode 15, I get expected results for each word, not what you state in your question.

Comment: so is just the simulator or my Xcode install being weird?

Comment: Apparently. I just tried it with Xcode 14.3 and it works there as well. Do the usual. Clean build, restart Xcode.

Comment: What locale is your device? Is it an English-based locale?

Comment: my device language is set to English but I am in Malaysia. Just tried Malay words and getting the same issue so I doubt that's the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your problem, as your code works for me (on US-configured device). So I suspect it is something with respect to the languages installed on the device.

I would first make sure your device has the necessary assets. Check with [`availableTagSchemes(for:language:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/naturallanguage/nltagger/2976621-availabletagschemes), and if you don’t have `.lexicalClass` for `.english`, then call asynchronous method [`requestAssets(for:tagScheme:completionHandler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/naturallanguage/nltagger/3194203-requestassets), or its `async` brethren.

For example:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import NaturalLanguage

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var result: String = "Processing"
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(result)
            .padding()
            .task {
                await example()
            }
    }
    
    func example() async {
        let unit: NLTokenUnit = .word
        let scheme: NLTagScheme = .lexicalClass
        let language: NLLanguage = .english
        let options: NLTagger.Options = [.omitPunctuation, .omitWhitespace]

        let text = "The ripe taste of cheese improves with age."
        let range = text.startIndex..<text.endIndex
        
        if !NLTagger.availableTagSchemes(for: unit, language: language).contains(scheme) {
            do {
                result = "Requesting assets"
                try await NLTagger.requestAssets(for: language, tagScheme: scheme)    
            } catch {
                print(error)
                result = "error: " + error.localizedDescription
                return
            }
        }
        
        let tagger = NLTagger(tagSchemes: [scheme])
        tagger.string = text
        // tagger.setLanguage(language, range: range)
        result = tagger
            .tags(in: range, unit: .word, scheme: scheme, options: options)
            .map { tag, tokenRange in "\(text[tokenRange]): \(tag?.rawValue ?? "Unknown")" }
            .joined(separator: "\n")
    }
}
```

If that still doesn’t work, I’d suggest temporarily changing the `scheme` to `.language` and see what language it is attempting. You will get the `OtherWord` if the language doesn’t match the language presented in the text (though in my experience, it does a good job figuring this out on its own). But if you want, you can explicitly set the language (as shown in that line of code that has been commented out).

Comment: We've been facing this same issue and when I run Rob's code above, the code hangs on the call to NLTagger.requestAssets; this call never seems to complete. We've tried erasing the simulator's contents and settings, installing languages, changing regions, nothing seems to do it. @Harris001, you accepted the above answer, so the above code works for you?

Comment: @PhilippeBoudreau, it hangs for me as well. Did it work for you?

Comment: Are you guys seeing this behavior in only the simulator, or on physical devices, too?

Comment: @Shahab No, never found a way to make this work.

Comment: @Rob We've moved on to a new project since then, but if I recall correctly, this was a problem for both simulator and physical device.

Comment: @Shahab – Two observations: First, I seem to recall some reference to the fact that the loading of these assets is very slow (though it is escaping me at this point). So make sure you give it enough time. Second, if you continue to have a problem and have a reproducible example, I would advise opening a ticket at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/.

Comment: Thanks @Rob, I think I should file a ticket By the way, I tried this on simulator.

Comment: Yeah, I’d really encourage you to reproduce the problem on a physical device, because simulators definitely have edge-cases. Regardless, good luck!

Comment: @Shahab FWIW, we submitted a bug via Feedback Assistant on Sept. 11th, 2023. The ID number is FB13153840. We did observe this issue on both simulator and devices.